# Digital filter of image in Fourier space

Tags: image-processing, fourier-analysis

Consider the contour plot below, of a function f(x,y) - which is calculated numerically by solving some equations.
If one looks carefully, one can observe two types of waves, to the left and right of the depression at (0,0). To the right we see waves of long wavelength (only two crests are visible actually). The waves to the left, on the other hand, are much more closely spaced and much less intense, but one can still distinguish them.
Let us ignore the vertical stripes, which are of no interest.

[image: real-space image]

Now if we take the 2D Fourier transform of the data, we get a picture like this:

[image: fourier]

The very small circle in the center corresponds to the waves of large separation, and the other 2 circles correspond to the washed out, closely-spaced waves.

My question is, what type of manipulation can I do (some filtering/convolution comes to mind) in order to give more weight to the washed-out waves to the left (make them more visible)?

**Edit:**

Just to clarify the above. I am not interested in any of the parallel vertical lines in the real-space plot, either to the right or to the left. What I am interested in are the very small parabolic waves very close to the center of the image, on the left side. I try to point them out in the zoom below, because they might be hard to spot in the original plot.

[image: zoom]

**Edit 2:**

I would prefer a way of selecting just the waves which correspond to a certain ring in the Fourier transformed image, something like a band pass filter which selects one ring. That is because I suspect that the close-spaced waves on the left of the center correspond to one particular ring only (the one pointed to by the blue arrow in the fourier plot).

The main motivation for doing things like this is that then I want to apply the same method to the problem below:

```
data = Import["http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=ieiLy8AD"];
img = Image[Rescale[data], ImageSize -> 400]
```

[image: space-mat]

In this image, the washed out waves to the left of the dark central point are even weaker. My gut feeling is that they can be best brought out by filtering in Fourier space.

However, I am willing to accept any answer that can **transform this last image to one where the small ripples are seen clearly** and then **make a cut of that 2D plot to calculate their wavelength** (along the y=0 axis for instance).

Comment: In case of confusion: I am in fact only interested in the **last image** (the one corresponding to the raw data).

Comment: So why not just do what you suggest yourself? Multiply your fourier domain picture by something which highlights the modes you are interested in, since you know where they are in fourier space.

Comment: @AndrewJaffe simply because I don't know **how** to do it in practice :))

Answer (score 13):

You could simply remove the vertical waves (e.g. by subtracting the median of each column) and histogram modification. Using @bill s's cropped image:

```
img = Image[
  ImageData[
    ColorConvert[Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/EvjuW.png"], 
     "Grayscale"]][[;; , ;; , 1]]]; (* remove alpha channel *)
columnMedian = Median[ImageData[img]];
medianRemoved = # - columnMedian & /@ ImageData[img];
ImageAdjust[Image[medianRemoved]]
```

This effectively removes the vertical waves:

[image]

To enhance the contrast of the waves left and right of the center, I'd simply apply a function like this to each pixel:

```
contrastEnhancement = #/Sqrt[Abs[#] + .05] &;
Plot[contrastEnhancement[x], {x, -1, 1}]
```

[image]

```
ImageAdjust[Image[contrastEnhancement[medianRemoved]]]
```

[image]

Or, using ListPlot3D:

```
ListPlot3D[GaussianFilter[-contrastEnhancement[medianRemoved], 5], PlotRange -> All, ImageSize -> 600]
```

[image]

Comment: great work @nikie. one thing remains - isn't there some way of selecting just the waves which correspond to a certain ring in the Fourier transformed image? say something like a band pass filter which selects one ring? because i know that the close-spaced waves on the left of the center correspond to one particular ring only (namely the bright ring on the left of the 2D fft plot).

Comment: @Andrei: Could you upload the raw images (without ticks, legend)? In the cropped image, the Fourier transform contains all kinds of artifacts.

Comment: in fact, i would like to upload the raw data, but its a large matrix and i'm not sure how to do that

Comment: @Andrei, you could probably put the raw data on [Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/).

Comment: @nikie, i uploaded a better image and the raw data corresponding to it is now on Pastebin.

Comment: @Andrei: It's weird: if I import the data from Pastebin, and look at the fourier transform, it still doesn't look nearly as smooth and artifact-free as the one in your question.

Comment: @nikie, the FFT in my question corresponds to the image just above it, which is for a homogeneous system. The problem I am interested in, which is the last image of my question, being inhomogeneous will of course have a more complicated FFT, but one can still see circles (using exponential scale).

Answer (score 8):

It actually works pretty well to just subtract off a Gaussian-blurred copy of the image. This is effectively a cheap high-pass filter, but one that does not introduce any ringing (*i.e.* extra waves that were not present in the original image).

```
i1 = Image[ImageData[ColorConvert[Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/EvjuW.png"], 
      "Grayscale"]][[;; , ;; , 1]]]; (* image loading code borrowed from @nikie's answer *)
j1 = ImageAdjust@ImageSubtract[i1, GaussianFilter[i1, 5]]
```

[image]

```
i2 = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/aIFO0.png"];
j2 = ImageAdjust@ImageSubtract[i2, GaussianFilter[i2, 5]]
```

[image]

Comment: nice! is there any way to do the reverse, i.e. a kind of low-pass filter that gets rid of these small waves?

Comment: Just use the Gaussian-filtered image instead of subtracting it from the original?

Answer (score 7):

Some deconvolve algorithm can not recover fine details very well, which is of course a shortcoming. However, by taking advantage of this kind of shortcoming, we can separate fine detailed structures from large scale structures effectively.

We borrow the same image loader from nikie's answer:

```
img = Image[
        ImageData[ColorConvert[
          Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/EvjuW.png"], 
          "Grayscale"]][[;; , ;; , 1]]];
```

First we blur `img` with a kernel whose "width" is close to the *characteristic scale* of the fine structure we want, which will *suppress* it maximally:

```
imgblur   = ImageConvolve[img, GaussianMatrix[7]];
```

Then we choose a *proper* (in the sense of relatively incapable of obtaining *sharp* images) deconvolve algorithm, say the Wiener filter:

```
imgdeblur = ImageDeconvolve[imgblur, GaussianMatrix[7], Method -> "Wiener"];
```

At last we subtract `imgdeblur` from `img` and adjust the contrast, brightness and gamma correction. Hopfully we have filtered out most of the large scale structures:

```
ImageSubtract[img, imgdeblur] // ImageCrop[#, 120] & // ImageAdjust[#, {0, 7, .5}] &
```

[image: result image]

For the remained vertical bars, in my opinion they look like well-fitted for some sine wave, so it should not be hard to filter out by 1-D Fourier transformation along the horizontal axis.

Or we can simply take the average along vertical axis to separate the sine-like background:

```
sinebg = Image[ConstantArray[
                    Mean[ImageData[imgsubed]],
                    {ImageDimensions[imgsubed][[2]]}]]

ImageSubtract[imgsubed, sinebg] // ImageAdjust
```

[image: result 2]

Answer (score 4):

Another approach would be to use a wavelet method: to multiply the wavelet coefficients at a specified level by some given factor, and then invert. In this implementation, start with the removal of the vertical features as suggested by nikie.

```
img = Image[ImageData[ColorConvert[Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/EvjuW.png"], 
        "Grayscale"]][[;; , ;; , 1]]];
columnMedian = Median[ImageData[img]];
medianRemoved = # - columnMedian & /@ ImageData[img];
imgProc = ImageAdjust[Image[medianRemoved]];
```

The technique is to pick a given level/scale, multiply the wavelet coefficients at that level/scale by a constant, and then take the inverse wavelet transform. Because it's hard to predict what levels and scales might be the best for a given image, it's implemented as a manipulate so it's easy to scan through and pick the most informative images.

```
Manipulate[swt = StationaryWaveletTransform[imgProc];
   mapWave = WaveletMapIndexed[ImageMultiply[#, m] &, swt, level];
   ImageAdjust[InverseWaveletTransform[mapWave]],
   {{level, {0,0,0,2}, "level"}, Dynamic[swt[All][[All, 1]]]}, {{m, 20, ""}, 0.1, 40}]
```

[image]

Here are a couple of other snapshots with different settings:

[image][image]